# ios 4 website issue media query or viewport

Tags: ios4, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport, iphone-4

i have programmed a website, for a client and now im developing a smartphone template.
I used max-device-width as media query to separate smartphone and tablet.
Everythng is working fine, but iphone 4 zooms the website.
I dont know if i defined viewport wrong or is a bug?
Website is:http://mksgmbh.com 
I used following Viewport

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi' name='viewport' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

I tried to set initial-scale to 1 but it doesnt work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I look at the site now you have mulitple viewport tags. Try removing them all and replacing them with either

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

or if you want to prevent user zooming:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

UPDATE
Also, in you media queries you use max-device-width, e.g.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 760px) {
...
}
```

Unless you are trying to target specific devices, you could try just

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
...
}
```

Device width and width aren't the same thing and for responsive design, width will usually get the results you want. [This link has some more background info](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml) about the differences

Hope this helps!

Comment: It helped a bit, but there is a little bug too.
initial-scale=1.0 does not fit completely i have to zoom out, in android and in ios too.